# Lambda Calculus: alpha conversion

Tags: lambda, alpha, lambda-calculus

This is an alpha conversion. Although I have completed this, I am not too sure whether this is a correct answer or not.

```
λx y.((λx y.x) x ((λx. x) y)) ((λx y. y)((λy. y) x) y)
=λx y.((λx1 y1. x1) x((λx2. x2) y1)) ((λx3 y2. y2)((λy3. y3) x3) y)
```

Is this a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You've made two mistakes. The bolded variables are not in scope when you use them:

λx y.((λx1 y1. x1) x((λx2. x2) **y1**)) ((λx3 y2. y2)((λy3. y3) **x3**) y)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, could you please tell me what the answer should be coz i still fell a little bit confuse about this? thanks!

Comment: sepp, I would also like to know this, what is the answer so how should it be changed?

Comment: λx y.((λa b.a)  x ((λc.c)  y))  ((λd e.e)((λf.f)x)y)